# Before method with multiple role restrictions

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im curious to know if it is possible to prevent users who don't have a role of owner or administrator from accessing certain controllers in a laravel application?

Comment: Sure it is possible, but we are not going to do all the work for you. Try it by yourself first (I'm certain there are tutorials about this out there on the internet) and if you have a specific problem, ask again.

Comment: Well I've seen examples like belong lukasgeiter however what if it's multiple types of users.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right but I'm just gonna throw some ideas at you ;)
One approach is to have a number for each role and the higher ones include the permission of the lower ones. so you can check if the "permission level" is high enough.
If that's not flexible enough, it get's more complicated...
Whatever you do, you'll at least need a roles table that's referenced by the users table. probably via a pivot table. Maybe try to pose your question more specific if you want a more detailed answer

Comment: I do have a roles table and a users table but no pivot table because I figured why have one if a user can only have one role at a time.

Comment: I have a users table with a field called role_id which references the id in the roles table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You can do this with a route filter.

routes.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth.admin'), function()
  {

    // Your routes    

  }
]);
```

and in filters.php

```
Route::filter('auth.admin', function()
{
  // logic to set $isAdmin to true or false      

  if(!$isAdmin)
  {
    return Redirect::to('login')->with('flash_message', 'Please Login with your admin credentials');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks however what if I have more than one type of user such as an administrator or owner can access.

Comment: @user3732216 - Then you simply add a new filter with your specific rule-set. 

Alternatively, you can use a package called https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry or their paid-for sentinel package. However I personally am not happy with their documentation (or lack of) which means that you have to do some hacky stuff in order to do some out-of-the ordinary things.

Answer (score 1):

Route filters have already been proposed but since your filter should be **Controller** specific you might want to try [controller filters](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#controller-filters).

First off, lets add this your controller(s)

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter(function()
    {
         // check permissions
    });
}
```

This function gets called before a controller action is executed.

In there it depends on you what you want to do. I'm just guessing now, because I don't know your exact architecture but I suppose you want to do something like this:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$role = $user->role->identifier;

if($role !== 'admin' && $role !== 'other-role-that-has-access'){
    App::abort(401); // Throw an unauthorized error
}
```

Instead of throwing an error you could also make a redirect, render a view or do basically whatever you want. Just do something that stops further execution so your controller action doesn't get called.

**Edit**

Instead of using  Closure function, you can use predefined filters (from the routes.php or filters.php)

```
$this->beforeFilter('filter-name', array('only' => array('fooAction', 'barAction')));
```

For more information, check out the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#controller-filters)

Comment: This is great but I have quite a few of these. So is there a way I can do this as in the routes file or is this suited for the filters file.

Comment: I personally don't use Controller filters. I prefer keeping this logic in the routes file. (separation of concerns and keeping code clean) Just embed the controller inside a `Route::group` with a before filter.

Comment: @Gravy That's true. In my opinion its a bit a matter of taste and requirements. E.g. wrapping every controller route in a group because it has different roles doesn't appeal to me. (for me a group should be multiple routes).
I know you can specify filters without a group but in some cases not as detailed (for specific actions) as you can with controller filters